# com.google.android.gms.common.api.b: 16: Cannot find a matching credential

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin, gcloud

[ApiException 16](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes#CANCELED): Cannot find a matching credential.

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.b: 16: Cannot find a matching credential.
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.w.b(SourceFile:1)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbbc.zbb(SourceFile:1)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbab.zba(Unknown Source:22)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbb.onTransact(Unknown Source:20)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1321)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1280)
```

I have tested I think everything but still...!
I created all credentials manually on gcloud for **debug**, **upload key**, and **play store signing key**.

I can get the accounts list and sign-in in debug mode, and when generate signed apk with my upload keystore.
But when I release the app-bundle to play store it won't work. It is not opening the list of gmail accounts. I have test it with

```
setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts false / true.
```

I have check google-service.json and it seems fine. And Google authentication is enabled in firebase console.

I have to mention there are 3 apps inside one project and one of them is working fine completely!

Any Ideas!?